# Bot doesn't wait for reaction and also he doesn't send message when collected because of Emded error

Tags: javascript, async-await, bots, embed, discord.js

So my bot should wait for a reaction of the user and then he should send a message, sometimes he waits (i think because of the internet connection),but mostly not as you can see in this screenshot: https://ibb.co/9gmfcr8 what is a problem, but even when i would suggest something, then he doesn't send the message to the specific channel, instead i get the error: `RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.`/`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.` Idk why he doesn't wait for the reaction or why he wouldn't send the suggestion. I would be thankful for any advice/solution.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggest',
    aliases: ['sug', 'suggestion'],
    description: 'Suggest something for the Bot',
    async execute(message, client, args) {
        try {
        const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

        const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('0x0099ff')
            .setDescription(`Suggestion categories`)
            .addField(`For what you want to suggest something?`, `\nA: I want to suggest something for the Website/Servers/Discord Server\nB: I want to suggest something for the CloudX Bot \n\nPlease react to this message with A or B`)


        message.channel.send(Embed).then(async function (message) {
            await message.react("")
            await message.react("")
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id;
        }

        await message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1 })
            .then(async collected => {
                const reaction = collected.first();

                if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

                    await message.channel.send(`Please provide a suggestion for the Website/Servers/Discord Server or cancel this command with "cancel"!`)

                    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, })
                        .then(async (collected) => {
                            try{
                            if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') {
                                message.reply("Your suggestion has been cancelled.")
                            }
                            else {
                                const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
                                    .setColor('0x0099ff')
                                    .setAuthor(message.author.tag)
                                    .addField(`New Suggestion:`, `${collected.first().content}`)
                                    .setFooter(client.user.username, "attachment://CloudX.png")
                                    .setTimestamp();

                                const channel = await client.channels.fetch("705781201469964308")
                                await channel.send({embed: embed1, files: [{
                                    attachment:'CloudX.png',
                                    name:'CloudX.png'
                                }]})

                                await message.channel.send(`Your suggestion has been filled to the staff team. Thank you!`)
                                }
                            } catch (error) {
                                console.log(error)
                            } 
                        })
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
                    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

                    await message.channel.send(`Please provide a suggestion for the CloudX Bot or cancel this command with "cancel"!`)

                    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, })
                        .then(async (collected) => {
                            try{
                            if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') {
                                message.reply("Your suggestion has been cancelled.")
                            }
                            else {
                                const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
                                    .setColor('0x0099ff')
                                    .setAuthor(message.author.tag)
                                    .addField(`New Suggestion:`, `${collected.first().content}`)
                                    .setFooter(client.user.username, "attachment://CloudX.png")
                                    .setTimestamp();

                                const channel = await client.channels.fetch("702825446248808519")
                                await channel.send({embed: embed2, files: [{
                                    attachment:'CloudX.png',
                                    name:'CloudX.png'
                                }]})

                                await message.channel.send(`Your suggestion has been filled to the staff team. Thank you!`)
                            }
                            } catch (error) {
                            console.log(error)
                            } 
                        })
                }    
            })
        })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    },
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work for what I assume you want,

Tested and working as of : Tue May 5 2:52 AM

```js
    const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')


    // call the lord EmojiMessageMan to handle reactions
    async function emojiMessageMan(message, validReactions) {

        // validReactions = ["one", "two"]
        for (const reaction of validReactions) await message.react(reaction);

        // filter
        const filter = (reaction, user) => validReactions.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && (!user.bot)

        // returns emoji the user reacted with
        return message
            .awaitReactions(filter, {
                max: 1,
            })
            .then(collected => collected.first() && collected.first().emoji.name);
    }

    // define embeds
    const mainEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('0x0099ff')
        .setDescription(`Suggestion categories`)
        .addField(`For what you want to suggest something?`, `\nA: I want to suggest something for the Website/Servers/Discord Server\nB: I want to suggest something for the CloudX Bot \n\nPlease react to this message with A or B`)


    // sends mainEmbed and await for reactions

    let mainEmbedMsg = "";
    await message.channel.send(mainEmbed).then((message) => {
        mainEmbedMsg = message
    })
    let mainEmbedEmoji = await emojiMessageMan(mainEmbedMsg, ["", ""])
    if (mainEmbedEmoji == "") {
        let promptMessage = await message.channel.send(`Please provide a suggestion for the Website/Servers/Discord Server or cancel this command with "cancel"!`)

        const Messagefilter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        var userResponse;
        var userMsg;
        await message.channel.awaitMessages(Messagefilter, { max: 1, }).then((collected) => {
            userResponse = collected.first().content.toLowerCase()
            userMsg = collected.first()
        })

        if (userResponse == "cancel") {
            message.channel.send("Your Suggestion Has Been Cancelled").then((msg) => {
                msg.delete(5000)
            })
            mainEmbedMsg.delete()
            userMsg.delete()
            message.delete()
            promptMessage.delete()
            return;
        }


        const bigA = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('0x0099ff')
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag)
            .addField(`New Suggestion:`, `${userMsg}`)
            .setFooter(client.user.username, "attachment://CloudX.png")
            .setTimestamp();

        const channel = await client.channels.fetch("705781201469964308")

        await channel.send({
            embed: bigA,
            files: [{
                attachment: 'CloudX.png',
                name: 'CloudX.png'
            }]
        })

        await message.channel.send(`Your suggestion has been filled to the staff team. Thank you!`).then((msg) => {
            msg.delete(5000)
        })

    } else if (mainEmbedEmoji == "") {

        let promptMessage = await message.channel.send(`Please provide a suggestion for the CloudX Bot or cancel this command with "cancel"!`)
        const Messagefilter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

        var userResponse;
        var userMsg;
        await message.channel.awaitMessages(Messagefilter, { max: 1, }).then((collected) => {
            userResponse = collected.first().content.toLowerCase()
            userMsg = collected.first()
        })

        if (userResponse == "cancel") {
            message.channel.send("Your Suggestion Has Been Cancelled").then((msg) => {
                msg.delete(5000)
            })
            mainEmbedMsg.delete()
            userMsg.delete()
            message.delete()
            promptMessage.delete()
            return;
        }

        const bigB = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('0x0099ff')
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag)
            .addField(`New Suggestion:`, `${userResponse}`)
            .setFooter(client.user.username, "attachment://CloudX.png")
            .setTimestamp();

        const channel = await client.channels.fetch("702825446248808519")

        await channel.send({
            embed: bigB,
            files: [{
                attachment: 'CloudX.png',
                name: 'CloudX.png'
            }]
        })
        await message.channel.send(`Your suggestion has been filled to the staff team. Thank you!`).then(msg => {
            msg.delete(5000)
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response but thank you 1000000000 times, i kiss your virtual eyes, you are a hero

Answer (score 0):

The error means that one of your embed lines is empty. Specifically, your field value. addField takes 3 parameters but you only used two. You need to add a comma after the field and add the boolean true

Comment: thanks but you also don't know what I made wrong so he doesn't wait for the reaction and also he doesnt't reacts to "cancel"